# Nonabelian group with all irreducible representations one-dimensional

Tags: representation-theory

All irreducible representations of an abelian group are one-dimensional.
For a finite group, the coverse is also true - if all irreducible representations are one-dimensional then the group is abelian.

> Is there a nonabelian group $G$ such that all of its finite-dimensional complex irreducible representations are one-dimensional (such group $G$ is necessarily infinite of course)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If "representation" means "finite-dimensional representation," then it turns out that you can find nonabelian $G$ whose only representations are trivial!

Groups that have faithful linear representations are called *linear*, and a theorem due to Malcev asserts that a finitely generated linear group is [residually finite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residually_finite_group). Taking the contrapositive, it follows that a finitely generated group that is not residually finite cannot be linear. And inspecting the proof of Malcev's theorem, you can squeeze out another result: a finitely generated group which admits a nontrivial representation admits a nontrivial map to a finite group. So to find a finitely generated group with no nontrivial representations, it suffices to find a finitely generated group with no subgroups of finite index. The [Higman group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman_group) was the first known such group.

Note also that if $G$ is residually finite then whether or not $G$ is finitely generated it's still true that $G$ is abelian iff its finite-dimensional irreducible representations are all $1$-dimensional (exercise). Many familiar groups are residually finite, so this rules out examples that are too easy.

Another strategy for constructing examples is to find [infinite simple groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_group#Infinite_simple_groups) with cardinality strictly larger than that of $\mathbb{R}$ (the same as the cardinality of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$), since any nontrivial finite-dimensional representation of such a group is necessarily faithful. Examples include $\text{PSL}_3(F)$ where $F$ is a field of cardinality strictly larger than $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm not sure how to deal with infinite-dimensional irreducible representations.

Comment: I did mean finite-dimensional representations (edited accordingly)